# Function printing address instead of items after split

Tags: python, function, split

One of my class materials had this block of code that I couldn't run in VSC due to the print line replacing return.

The output was the address of the string instead of the split values of the list. I can't seem to tack on the split anywhere else than after the line, as I saw some people suggested to do something like yum = yum.split. Any help?

```
def hungry(filename):
    food = open(filename)
    yumm=[]
    for line in food:
      yumm= yumm+[line.split()] //forgot the parenthesis here
        
    //yumm=yumm.split()
    print(yumm)
hungry("3/nomnom.txt")
```

Edit: I'm an idiot, thanks to the legend who brought it up. I missed the parenthesis after split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis after the first call to `split`. It's a method and it needs to be called :

```py
for line in food:
    yumm= yumm+[line.split()]
```

And if you need to concatenate your lists, you probably meant to do `yumm + line.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

If line is a string, then line.split is a function that lets you split a string based on a provided delimiter, as such:

```
"Hello, world!".split(" ")
# Prints ["Hello,", "world!"]
```

As such, you would want this:

```
def hungry(filename):
    food = open(filename)
    yumm=[]
    for line in food:
        yumm= yumm + line.split(" ")

    print(yumm)
hungry("3/nomnom.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate! Your solution is really helpful. I'm new to programming but it's great that python has so many ways to produce the same solutions.